# std::string to std::regex

Tags: c++, regex

I'm trying to convert a string to a regex, string looks like so:

```
std::string term = "apples oranges";
```

and I wanted the `regex` to be `term` with all spaces replaced by any character and any length of characters and I thought that this might work:

```
boost::replace_all(term , " " , "[.*]");
std::regex rgx(s_term);
```

so in `std::regex_search` `term` would return true when looking at:

```
std::string term = "apples pears oranges";
```

but its not working out, how do you do this properly?

Comment: You should doulbe check it with a tester.  Your regex will fail: https://regex101.com/r/tGICBc/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do everything with `basic_regex`, no need for `boost`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string search_term = "apples oranges";
    search_term = std::regex_replace(search_term, std::regex("\\s+"), ".*");

    std::string term = "apples pears oranges";
    std::smatch matches;

    if (std::regex_search(term, matches, std::regex(search_term)))
        std::cout << "Match: " << matches[0] << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "No match!" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/gyzfCj

This will return when 1st occurrence of `apples<something>oranges` found. If you need match the whole string, use `std::regex_match`

Answer (score 2):

You should use `boost::replace_all(term , " " , ".*");` that is without the `[]`. The `.*` simply means any character, and any number of them.

Comment: To elaborate, `[.*]` means "Only match one of the literal `.` or `*` characters".

Comment: ".*" fails as well